# Do different objects with different surface reaction feel the same pressure under a mass?

Tags: pressure, surface-tension, weight

Let's imagine somehow your hand could change its surface reaction, and becomes as soft as a rubber ball.
Now if we put it on a table (a hard surface) and put an 1kg object on it, do we still feel the 1kg weight/pressure even if the hand becomes flatten, or just the pressure needed until the flatten state?

What if the hand is softer (water or air / lower surface reaction) and this time object gets floated inside (I mean the hand surrounds the surface of the object) do I still feel 1 kg?
What if we insert our hand between 2 layers a soft substance like foam, untill we can't feel the object, do we feel its weight?

Sorry if it's a silly example, I actually want to know the the differences between the surface reaction or tension between an elastic and hard surface

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Applied pressure is weight per unit area.
So long as the mass is not moving relative to the material supporting it, you could count both together as one object.  The total weight would be the weight of the supporting material plus the weight of the mass.  Whatever keeps this from moving downward over time would feel a weight increase of the entire mass.  If the mass is floating within, you would notice it more as a reaction to the buoyancy force than as a normal force.
Pressure is completely different.  This depends on area of contact just as much as weight.  This is the principle that makes hypodermic needles possible.  If the weight is distributed over a tiny area, pressure is enormous.  A soft or almost liquid surface could spread the weight over a larger area and decrease the pressure.  As an extreme example, consider a wood toothpick with one small and sharp metal point.  If in a jar of water, the weight of that toothpick would be distributed over the entire surface area at the bottom of the jar.  If it were rather in direct contact with your hand, the small weight could exert enough pressure to penetrate your skin.